# How to denote a volta that should only be used after jump back to the Segno?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, musical-forms, musescore, repeats

I have an arrangement which looks a bit like this:
[image: simplified score showing form]
First there is an intro, and then we play bars 2-5 twice, and then jump to bar 9. When we reach *D.S. al Coda*, we jump back to the segno and play bars 2-3, and then jump to bar 6.

But how should I show this correctly?
(An extra plus if the solution also works with playback in MuseScore, but that is not a requirement.)

I might add that in the real arrangement, the repeated section is 44 bars long, and the part that lies between the "After segno"-volta and the Coda is 17 bars, so I would really like to avoid writing it out twice. It fits on one page now, and I want to keep it that way.

#### EDIT:

The segno should be at bar 3 and not 2. Not that I think this makes a huge difference, but just in case.

And yes, I'm aware that readability trumps compactness yada yada. Let's skip that part of the discussion please. The reason I want one page instead of two is so we can fit more songs in our song binders. And sometimes it already is a problem to carry them, so fixing more binders is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

What you have written is about as clear as possible I think.   Don't do it in a part that will be sight-read.  But then, try to avoid coda jumps and the like completely on a part intended for sight-reading.

Answer (score 2):

Even with your description it's unclear how to follow. Perhaps you should put a termination double-bar at the "DS al coda" sign, and then put the "go to Coda" sign at the start of bar 4, and all the "coda-only" measures written in a following line, separate from the DS end-of-line.
If you mean the "after segno" is played after the 1-2 repeat as well, then maybe clarify by replacing your "1-2" with "1,2 ONLY" and "afterSegno" written as "3 ONLY" .

From a performer's point of view "fitting on one page" is not a good reason to make the sequence complicated.  At the very least, consider writing both the first-time and the post-Segno parts into the same physical measure bars. Mark 1-2 with stems up and 3 with stems down.

Comment: I have double bars in my real arrangement, but as far as I know, they don't "mean" anything, except for "look here". That's why I excluded them in the image.

Answer (score 1):

For  our bands at school I used to notate "lead-sheet- like" the sections numbering: intro AABACAD etc.   then give advices about the program of the performance. I think this solution would fit best of yours and any similar problem.